# Complexity of the vertices of a decomposed simple polygon to its cells

Tags: computational-geometry

Given a simple polygon (without holes), consider a given decomposition of the polygon into convex sub-polygons. Suppose there are m number of convex sub-polygons and the number of the vertices of the decomposed grid is v. I am looking for the complexity of v in m.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This question is off-topic here. Try on Computer Science. (I don't think that convexity matters; consider a planar graph.)

Comment: I want to know if v is in O(mlogm)? We already know that v is O(m^2). But it seems that m^2 is not a good upper bound. Just to make it clear m^2 comes from the fact that m lines can have m^2 intersection points